# Overthought how to load and edit a file

Tags: c, file, text, load, edit

I have this assignment to be able to save a list to a file, then load it and edit the file. The save part is a short, but I feel like the load part is way to long and overthought, and now I wonder if anyone know a way to simplify my code, because it feels like it's way to complicated.

This is what i have at the moment:

```
void loadList(struct ShoppingList* list)
{
    FILE* fileHandler;
    float tempFloatAmount;
    int firstSpace = 0, secondSpace = 0, tempNameCount = 0, tempUnitCount = 0;
    int length, count;

    list->length = 0;
    struct GrocaryItem* temp;
    temp = NULL;

    char input[20];
    char tempName[20];
    char tempCharAmount[1000];
    char tempUnit[10];

    input[0] = '\0';
    tempName[0] = '\0'; 
    tempCharAmount[0] = '\0';
    tempUnit[0] = '\0'; 

    char readLine[1024];

    printf("Enter the name of the .txt file (without the '.txt') where you want to get your shoppinglist: ");
    scanf_s("%s", input, 20);

    fileHandler = fopen(input, "r");
    if (fileHandler == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file %s", input);
        return; 
    }
    while (fgets(readLine, 1024, fileHandler) != NULL)
    {

        length = strlen(readLine);

        count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (readLine[i] == ' ') 
            {
                count++;
                if (count == 1) 
                {
                    firstSpace = i; 
                }
                if (count == 2)
                {
                    secondSpace = i;
                }
            }
        }
        tempNameCount = 0;  
        for (int i = 0; i < firstSpace; i++)
        {
            tempName[i] = readLine[i];  
            tempNameCount++;
        count = 0;  
        for (int i = firstSpace + 1; i < secondSpace; i++)  
        {
            tempCharAmount[count] = readLine[i]; 
            count++;    
        }
        tempFloatAmount = atof(tempCharAmount); 
        tempUnitCount = 0;  
        count = 0;  
        for (int i = secondSpace + 1; i < length - 1; i++)

            tempUnit[count] = readLine[i];
            tempUnitCount++;
            count++;    
        }

        temp = (struct GrocaryItem*)realloc(list->itemList, sizeof(struct GrocaryItem) * (1 + list->length));   

        if (temp != NULL)   
        {
            list->itemList = temp;

            count = 0;  
            for (int i = 0; i < tempNameCount + 1; i++)
            {
                if (i < tempNameCount)  
                {
                    list->itemList[list->length].productName[count] = tempName[i];
                    count++;    
                }
                else    
                {
                    list->itemList[list->length].productName[count] = '\0';
                    count++;    
                }
            }

            list->itemList[list->length].amount = tempFloatAmount;

            count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < tempUnitCount + 1; i++)
            {
                if (i < tempUnitCount)
                {
                    list->itemList[list->length].unit[count] = tempUnit[i];
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    list->itemList[list->length].unit[count] = '\0';
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        list->length++; 
    }
    fclose(fileHandler);    
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the function works to your satisfaction, and you are just looking for ways to improve it.  Such a question would be better suited for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: would be better if you explain your intentions in various parts of the code with inline comments or something...

Comment: You needlessly go over the remaining input after you encountered the second space.

Comment: You do not terminate `tempCharAmount`. `atof` may encounter digits from a previous pass.

Comment: Instead of `if (i < tempNameCount)`, let the loop go to `tempNameCount` and add the termination after the loop. Also, why not use `strcpy` or `strncpy` instead of the loop?

Comment: Same for `tempUnitCount` loop.

Comment: If `temp == NULL` you still increment the list length though no item was added. You also continue reading input though a fatal error occurred (out of memory).

Comment: In summary: the whole thing can greatly be simplified and improved.